# how to highlight the words which are invalid in input given by a user

Tags: html, validation

how to highlight **only the words** which are invalid in input given by a user where i can make my custom invalid check function. 
e.g
hello this is very good and very nice. 
suppose this is the input by the user and suppose i want to highlight "very" and "this" or any other custom word.

I have tried putting html tag inside value but html does not parses inside value attribute of input tag.

Comment: Hey Welcome to StackOverflow - Share a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Try using **variable.split()** in reading the input. Store it in array using loop and check for errors and highlight

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply put html tags in input. To enable "rich text" capabilities, you'll have to use the [contenteditable HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable), like so...

```js
const words = [/(very)/gi, /(nice)/gi]
const highlightInput = () => {
 const richInput = document.getElementById('rich-input')
 let text = richInput.innerText

 words.forEach(x => {
  text = text.replace(x, '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')
 })
 
 richInput.innerHTML = text
}

document.getElementById('highlight').addEventListener('click', highlightInput)
```

```css
#rich-input{
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.highlighted{
  color:red;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Highlight!" id="highlight" />
</div>

<label>Enter your text below:</label>
<div id="rich-input" contenteditable="true">Hello this is very good and very nice</div>
```

Comment: hey in last line of html div with id='rich-input'  i am not having a div like that rather i want to highlight some words from the value of the input tag.